# how to fetch the after certain special character

Tags: oracle

I have a string 1234567789@9010.I want to fetch the value after @.In this case I want 9010.so I have written below function

res:=substr(str,charindex(str'@',1),length(str));

then the result is coming correctly but if string is having only 1234567789 then result is coming 12345677891234567789 .if the string does not have '@' then it should fetch 1234567789.

Comment: Are you sure this is Oracle? Oracle have no [`charindex`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/19/sqlrf/Single-Row-Functions.html#GUID-06062705-1EC8-44ED-89B8-0F0573B74EA2) function. And with `instr` it [works fine](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=6c043a04210c23ad292a1978c2c980ab) (you even doesn't need the third argument since Oracle's `substr` returns substring from the position until the end)

Answer (score 0):

Using `REGEXP_REPLACE` comes to mind:

```
SELECT REGEXP_REPLACE(val, '^.*@', '')
FROM yourTable;
```

We could also use `REGEXP_SUBSTR` with a capture group:

```
SELECT REGEXP_SUBSTR(val, '@(.*)$', 1, 1, NULL, 1)
FROM yourTable;
```